# JSON.NET deserializing to a DataSet fails consistently

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am deserializing json data from an online api.
The json can be deserialized using the following:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
```

Where jsonData is just a string containing the downloaded content.
When I try and perform the following action however:

```
DataSet master = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonData);
```

I get the following error:

> Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.

I have verified the validity of the json using multiple online resources.
What could be the problem?

The data I am trying to deserialize can be found here: [api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/latest/enUS/cards.json](https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/latest/enUS/cards.json)

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `jsonData` variable? It's possible that the JSON data is not in a format suitable for serializing to a data-set (e.g. it has nested elements)

Comment: Data can be found here: https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/latest/enUS/cards.json

Comment: It's just too long to post in a comment

Comment: You can't deserialize to a DataSet, you need to deserialize to a DataTable. A DataSet is a container for DataTables, it doesn't contain any data itself

Comment: JSON.Net provides facilities for deserialing to a DataSet and has worked previously. It can deserialize the data into a "dynamc" FastExpando type collection but will not deserialize to a DataSet as shown in the examples.

Comment: @user3081814 DataTable, not DataSet. If you think the data causes issues, post a sample that can produce the error  *in the question*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is supposed to work to DataSet, see their website for examples.